# Stop youtube video when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I am trying to get YouTube videos that I have on my site to stop playing when you either click the navigation arrows or circles. I am using the skrollr javascript library to create the parallax effects and placement of objects; a working model of the site can be seen [here](http://visual-element.us/projectsite/index.html).

The videos are embedded using the default sharing code from YouTube. I tried using the YouTube API guide but I just can't seem to get it to work. (still somewhat new to javascript).

I have also searched and used info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe) of using buttons and links to stop all videos but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Whilst I know you've had a shot at it, here is a useful link that be of help... https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started