# Video still playing when modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, bootstrap-modal

When I close the bootstrap modal, the video is still playing.
so what I want is : when I close the bootstrap modal, the sound of the video will stop.

here is the script Js

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and HTML code

```
<img id="myBtn" src="URL of button here" alt="" style="width: 70px; height:70px;" >

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <span class="close">x</span>
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <p>
                <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JY1ddEDcVV0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop embedded youtube iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe)

Comment: not the same issue jonmrich. My video is in a bootstratp modal not just embed in a page. I am not a pro that's why I have shared my code to help me

Comment: Egads. That's not how Bootstrap modals should be shown or hidden, and they have callbacks that should be used to start and stop playback.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is how to do it. You will need to completely re-write your JS. You can use `iframe.postMessage();` to play/pause the video. Here is an example of how to implement it:

```
<div id="videoWrapper">
   <iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JY1ddEDcVV0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <input onClick="toggleVideo('hide');" type='button'>
</div>


<script>
function toggleVideo(state) {
    var div = document.getElementById("videoWrapper");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}','*');
}
</script>
```

Also you can easily change `<input>` to you `<img>`.

Many thanks to [How to pause a YouTube player when hiding the iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe)

Hope this helps!

Comment: can't adapt it to my code - with modal. with your code Zoe the video will not be responsive that's why need to use modal boostrap

Comment: I can look at the code more closely in about 3 hours, until then, make sure that you are using `ByClass` and `ById` correctly. Sorry the code isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) to do this, but it will also require re-writing some of your code. I have adapted the linked example for your situation below.

### HTML

I have replaced the video with a placeholder `div` with the id `player`. Once the video is loaded by the YouTube API, it will replace this `div`. I have also added the class `close` to the `span` so we can refer to it by its class instead of the tag, which would allow you to have the X button on modals, but also use `span` tags elsewhere without causing conflicts.

```
<img id="myBtn" src="URL of button here" alt="" style="width: 70px; height:70px;" >

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

        <span class="close">x</span>
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <p>
                <div id="player"></div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### JavaScript

We need to do a few things:

1. Load the YouTube API

   ```
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
   ```
2. Load the video

   ```
   var player;
   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
       player = new YT.Player('player', {
             height: '390',
             width: '640',
             videoId: 'JY1ddEDcVV0',
             rel: '0',
             controls: '0',
             showinfo: '0'
           });
   });
   ```
3. Define the `stopVideo()` function

   ```
   function stopVideo() {
       player.stopVideo();
   }
   ```
4. Call `stopVideo()` every time you close the modal. Just simply add it into your "onclick" functions. You can also do these types of functions with jQuery exclusively, which I have shown an example of with the close button.

   ```
   $(".close").click(function() {
       modal.style.display = "none";
       stopVideo();
   });
   ```

### JavaScript all together

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
$(".close").click(function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    stopVideo();
});
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        stopVideo();
    }
}
var player;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'JY1ddEDcVV0',
          rel: '0',
          controls: '0',
          showinfo: '0'
        });
});

function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

Comment: I click on "myBtn" nothing happened. The modal disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution very simple.
I have added 1 line for span.onclick - when user click on  X

```
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";

$('iframe').attr('src', ''); //line added }
```

But I am facing an other issue : when I close the modal, and open it again,I want to allow the video to appear again. I got an answer but not very clar for me : " I suggest you create a clone of it before letting the document show it in the first place (i.e. before it autoplays)" 
can somebody helps?

Comment: With this solution you are removing the YouTube URL from the iframe, so it ends up like this: `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

If you want to go with this solution, you'll need to add the URL back in via the same method when you click on the button to open the modal, like this:

`btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    $('iframe').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/JY1ddEDcVV0?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0');
}
`

This solution will not be easily extendable if you add more modals/videos.