# Stop an iframe video using Angular 2

Tags: angular, iframe, ionic3

I am trying to play videos on an ionic 3 / Angular app. I need to put an overlay on the video so they can not click on the video to redirect them to the videos webpage. But now I have a problem with starting and stopping the video. I have created buttons that will do this but do not know how to get those buttons to actually start and stop the video.

Comment: Where is the video being streamed from?

Comment: I am streaming the video through Youtube.

Comment: Great, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165166/3483203) answer should help you.

Comment: I am using Angular not Angularjs

Comment: That answer is not Angularjs specific

Comment: That did not seem to help. I was not able to get jquery to run on angular 2

Comment: Thank you for this. This did help.