# pause playing youtube video when another is played using angular

Tags: angular, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have multiple youtube iframes in single page but problem is while one of the video is playing and user click on another to play this does not make the first one to stop. is there any work around using angular

Comment: add some code here so someone could help you better

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe)

Comment: @TheNsn666 I want solution in angular but this is pure js

Comment: @shaharyar did you try something ? can you open a stackblitz with the code ?

Comment: @TheNsn666 on an angular end I have done nothing