# is there a way to reload after removing an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

The 1 and 3 are id of button and v1 and v3 are id of iframe(youtube emmbedded).
i have already used a simple .show() and .hide() but the audio remained of hidden iframe so i am using .remove() and .show().
when i use .remove() the other iframe is gone completely and only iframe remains is of that button which i pressed which i want.
however when i press button 3 the removed iframe is not able to load, is there a way to reload it?

the iframes i am using are :-

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" id="v1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xGRjCa49C6U?modestbranding=1&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" ></iframe>

<iframe width="560" height="315" id="v3" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9V9wr1AaIxY?modestbranding=1&controls=0&autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" ></iframe>
```

and this is the js:-

```
$(function(){

  $('#1').on('click',function(){
    $('#v1').show();
        var getframe = document.getElementById("v3");
       getframe.remove();

  });

  $('#3').on('click',function(){
    $('#v3').show();
var getframe = document.getElementById("v1");
       getframe.remove();

  });

});
```

Comment: What about fixing the X of your X-Y issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358006/3702797

Comment: i will be going with @amal method, he solved my problem while letting the code remain same. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove()** method removes the element from the dom and its hard to reload.

So this can be done like the following.

- Load YouTube iFrame API:-

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

- Create two different players that references the existing iFrames

> ```
> $(function(){
> window.YT.ready(function() {
> var player1 = new YT.Player('v1');
> var player3 = new YT.Player('v3');
>
> $('#1').on('click',function(){
>     $('#v1').show();
>     player1.unMute();
>     
>     $('#v3').hide();
>     player3.mute();
>   });
>
>   $('#3').on('click',function(){
>     $('#v3').show();
>     player3.unMute();
>     
>     $('#v1').hide();
>     player1.mute();
>   });
> });
> });
> ```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaldassk/0t2j37ks/)

Hope this helps