# change url of PDF in this pdf.js demo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the url of the pdf in this pdf.js HTML5 pdf viewer, but when I do the canvas is blank instead of displaying the new pdf.

Why does it do this and how can I get it to display and pdf ?

Here it is: http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-helloworld-v2/1/edit

Comment: What's the alternate URL for the new PDF?

Comment: @Duniyadnd http://www.onwardsearch.com/UX-Career-Guide/UX-Career-Guide-Infographic.pdf

Comment: Did you try running it straight from that URL?

Comment: @Duniyadnd What do you mean? I've tried just viewing that URL in a browser that supports pdf viewing and the URL works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering my questions above - the problem probably lies with where the pdf file is located.

When you run it from jsbin.com - and you call in the pdf document you described in your comments, the browser console returns the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.onwardsearch.com/UX-Career-Guide/UX-Career-Guide-Infographic.pdf. Origin http://jsbin.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

These two threads on stackoverflow should help you further

[Why am I seeing an "origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error)

and

[XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

In the future, to look at the console frame in Chrome - Ctrl+Shift+J

Console frame in Firefox - get firebug add on - will save you a ton of time

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help and I will look into the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.