# XMLHttpRequest Cannot Load - not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm having an issue with two different pages on the same site.  Both are running the same Javascript, line for line... yet one is throwing me errors and one is not.  Please see the two following URLs...

http://www.gloprofessional.com/moist-hydration-mist - Click on the play in the left column
http://www.gloprofessional.com/info/learn-more/videos/ - Click on any video Link

When clicked, a fancybox link should be triggered, in which a youtube video should play.

Any ideas as to why one works, while another does not?  The main URL is running on Magento, while anything under the /info/ is expression engine.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why am I seeing an “origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” error here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error)

Answer (score 0):

One uses xhr(ajax) to load url from youtube and you cannot use xhr from different domain that you are in - and the other using iframe with youtube url which is fine (you have got still errors cause in there with frames permissions btw)

Comment: Thanks Adidi, but perhaps I'm confused... isn't the exact same code being executed in both places?

Comment: No - again - one try to load something using XHR from youtube - the other uses iframe by setting it's src to youtube URL - you can point iframe to whatever URL you want - although there are some sites blocking this

Comment: Am I missing where this is occurring?  
Link 1 - <a class="pageVideo fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/LSvSxu1xVdc?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1;rel=0">
Link 2 - <a class="pageVideo fancybox.iframe"  href="http://www.youtube.com/v/j4ywK87uNe8?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1;rel=0">

Both pages should be triggering an iframe method, why is one using XHR?

Comment: Cause this is what you see in the inspector (using chrome): "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.youtube.com/v/LSvSxu1xVdc?fs=1&autoplay=1;rel=0. Origin http://www.gloprofessional.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." - this is the error as you see

Answer (score 0):

Within the second link the contents are loaded within an iframe.

Within the mage site i assume the contents are loaded directly?
Use an iframe within the mage fancybox as well and it should work.