# cross domain issue with WSo2 Identity server rest call

Tags: jquery, ajax, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I tried to call rest api of Identity server. It's working perfectly from Curl command. But when trying from jquery-ajax it shows error like

OPTIONS http://abcd.server:8281/search No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery.js:8416
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abcd.server:8281/search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the right headers (allow-methods:options,get,put,etc,allow-origin) on the server side
same issue solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258820/cross-domain-issue-with-wso2-identity-server-rest)

Comment: Thanks , forced to add CORS headers to the request

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a common error related ajax. As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error). Did you see any error in WSO2IS logs or console