# Cross domain issue with WSo2 Identity server Rest

Tags: jquery, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have a oauth secured rest ([Sample](http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/apply-oauth2-0-base-security-for-rest-endpoint-with-wso2esb-4-6-0-and-wso2is-4-1-1-alpha/))in my WSO2 ESB server.When i try to call from ajax , it shows cross domain issue.

my ajax call is :-

```
jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer c791c67d8b272632d8e9e3ee9162179");
        },
        url: "http://192.168.1.27:8280/rest2",
        contentType :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        type: "GET", 
        async: false,
        error: function (jq, status, message) {
            console.info('A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message+JSON.stringify(jq));

        },

        success: function() { 
        alert('Success!'); 
    }

    });
```

Does anybody have solution  ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, You have to add some cross domain headers to server response.

Required cross domain headers
1. Access-Control-Allow-Origin
2. Access-Control-Allow-Methods
3. Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Thanks

Comment: Where I defined this