# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook with AngularJS and CORS is not working correctly .

My omniauth.rb is

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook,"xxxxx", "xxxxx",
:scope => 'email,user_birthday,read_stream', :display => 'popup'

end
```

Everything works if i use it as rails app and request. But when i try to call 'http:\localhost:3000\users\auth\facebook" via Angular JS

```
$http.get('/users/auth/facebook').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("back in success");
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });
    }
```

i see following error in JS console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&display=popup…thday%2Cread_stream&state=3352c1924bdbc9277f7b1070c38d67acf79b529f198323cb.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `'http://localhost:3000'` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

(The url is not displayed completely in console)

I added following line

```
config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Rack::Cors
```

but also this didn't work .

What is the best way or how can i override headers for OmniAuth ?

> I am using Angularjs and gem devise ,omniauth-facebook

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Emberjs and Google oauth. Haha pretty funny you're hitting this with Facebook/Angular and just submitted this question only 2 hours ago.

Comment: You are bumping into a same origin origin policy issue http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy . This may not work on local host, or you may need to proxy through rails. (This is a tip not full answer)

Comment: Go to http://enable-cors.org/ and follow the steps for your server/app  configuration

Comment: This question has 12 upvotes while every answer has 0 except one with 1. Surely someone has figured this out?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on your development environment you may want to try a workaround, by allowing you browser to run in a non-secure mode.

For Chrome on Windows, from CMD try:

```
> cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
> chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

The `--disable-web-security` flag will allow you to make cross domain requests. The `--user-data-dir` flag will allow you to open a new session **only** for development.

This is **just a workaround for you development work**! Don't use this in production or navigate to other sites in this session!

Comment: Certainly, there are many other workaround for the problem. Other links posted here are very useful!

Comment: I came ready to write this one answer, but since it's here, and since it's the best, it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm getting an "access is denied" on the console when I write those two commands. Any ideas?

Comment: Really confused, error went away after a bit of hiatus. Works with Chrome already open, so that wasn't the problem. No idea what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is Javascript cannot make cross-domain requests. This is done for security reasons so that a script cannot call a remote server and expose sensitive data.

Below is a link to a very good and simple explanation with a few options on how to get around it:

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

And here is a previous answer which has some good information as well:

[Why am I seeing an "origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error)

Answer (score 0):

If they don't have the header set then you can't force them to have the headers. Perhaps you should look at using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). However, mirroring through the server wouldn't be all that bad since you'll only have to deal with it at most once per visit, and more than likely once per user since so few people ever delete cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in server will make the track.
Like:
`ruby
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'`

In rails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting the data from the `https` secure site that is facebook to your site which is `http` so the latest browsers are not supporting cross allow origin.

The only solution is make your site support `https`.

Answer (score 0):

In your ApplicationController.rb add

```
  def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

For CORS you have to whitelist the domain you want to access from cross origin request on the server side

```
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
//star will allow all the domain you can specify also which url u want to access
```

on the client side,you have to set the header in config() as

```
   $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Answer (score 0):

some times that problem occurs because of browser.IE by default allow cross origin request. In chrome you will required to add one plugin that is "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *"and enabled it.