# YouTube API Academy

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just completed the YouTube API tutorials on Codecademy and successfully managed to display results relating to a given 'q' value in the console window provided using the following code:

```
// Helper function to display JavaScript value on HTML page.
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    // See http://goo.gl/PdPA1 to get a key for your own applications.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCR5In4DZaTP6IEZQ0r1JceuvluJRzQNLE');

    search();
}

function search() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: "Hello",
    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

and:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="response"></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having now is that I have taken this code and put it into my own local files with the intention of furthering my understanding and manipulating it work in a way which suits me, however it just returns a blank page. I assume that it works on Codecademy because they use a particular environment and the code used perhaps only works within that environment, I am surprised they wouldn't provide information on what changes would be required to use this outside of their given environment and was hoping someone could shed some light on this? Perhaps I am altogether wrong, if so, any insight would be appreciated.

Browser Console Output:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Comment: Anything in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: Updated with browser console output, thanks

Comment: You need to [set the origin](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#origin). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error) should help.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem but it was resolved when I used Xampp. What you have to do is install xampp on your machine and then locate its directory. After You will find a folder named "htdocs". Just move your folder containing both js and HTML file into this folder. Now you have to open Xampp Control Panel and click on start button for both - Apache and SQL server. Now open your browser and type in the URL:

http://localhost/"(Your htdocs directory name containing both of your pages)"

After this, click on .html file and you are done.