# $http({method}) not working but $http.get working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

**Problem Statement:** In my project I am using **$http({ method :
 'GET',  url : data : .....** param, for **get** and **Post** it works fine. But
 when I use same method in fiddle it will block my request. If I
 use $http.get(.... then it will work in jsfiddle dont know why

Can any one explain me what is difference between **$http.get('http://...**    and    **$http({mthod
:'GET',....})**

See these both example :

---

**1)** Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/84e02j4t/8/

```
var promise = $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc',
            data : entity,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            cache : false
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
```

ERROR : in first example see in console it will give you error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

---

**2)** using $http.get(... 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/qny7v23f/

```
 test: function (param) {

            $http.get('http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc', {
                params: {
                    query: param,
                    callback: 'YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback'
                }
            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return "there was an error";
            })
        }
    }
```

And I am using Cors app in chrome so it will add Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: Are you authorized to use that URL through JSFiddle? Both don't work at my end. Also note the URLs you are using in both cases are different.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error

Comment: i am using Cors application so it will work for second one but sam thing not working for 1 ) example

Answer (score 0):

CORS headers is required to be present on remote site, the one that you're requesting. Not yours