# Angularjs and Web service Issue

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am not getting data from Web service's response in angularjs using $http.get method.What cause is this?? It is directly goes to error part.

Web service code:

```
 @GET
 @Path("/getEmployeeList")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response getEmployeeList() {
    ArrayList<Employee> empList = (ArrayList<Employee>) employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    return Response.status(200).entity(empList).build();
}
```

Angular Js:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body  >

<div  ng-app="hello">
    <h1>Greeting</h1>
    <div ng-controller="home" >
      <div ng-repeat="a in greeting">
        <p>The Id is: {{a.empId}}</p>
        <p>The content is: {{a.firstName}}</p>
         <p>The content is: {{a.lastName}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
    </body>
  <script >
   var myApp = angular.module('hello', []);
  myApp.controller('home',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList")
    .success(function(data) {

        $scope.greeting = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      alert("Error") 
    });
 }]);

</script>

</body>
```

Json Data From Web services:
     URL:http://localhost:8080/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList

```
 [
{
    "empId": 1,
    "firstName": "Chirag",
    "lastName": "L"
},
{
    "empId": 2,
    "firstName": "Prashant",
    "lastName": "K"
}
]
```

Comment: console.info error details or put your browser in developer mode to get error details. I suspect the use of absolute uri. did you try using this one `/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList`?

Comment: I am getting following Error:Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: According to CORS, a different port is a different origin. You'll need to make sure your Jersey response includes a header of Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header at response....

```
@GET
@Path("/getEmployeeList")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response getEmployeeList() {
 ArrayList<Employee> empList = (ArrayList<Employee>)  employeeService.getAllEmployees();
 return Response.status(200).entity(empList).***header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")***.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$http does not pass the response data but the response to the success callback.
Therefore use:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
    }).error(function(response){
        alert("Error") 
});
```

For the CORS-error see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error).

Comment: then debug this function: set a breakpoint in your success callback and examine the value which is passed.

Comment: I am getting following Error:Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/restful-jersey-spring-demo/restws/employee/getEmployeeList. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: I would recomend using `.then(function successHandler() {}, function errorHandler() {})` because it returns promise implicitly which is not the case with `.success()` and `.error()`. Because of this, in provided example it is imposible to chain additional promise handlers which is very often needed during normal development.