# Using jQuery to get JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON response that shows like this:

```
{
  "gameId": 2540832082,
  "mapId": 12,
  "gameMode": "ARAM",
  "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
  "gameQueueConfigId": 65,
  "participants": [
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 32,
      "spell2Id": 7,
      "championId": 25,
      "profileIconId": 774,
      "summonerName": "MLG Elan",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 77477471,
      "runes": [],
      "masteries": [
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6111
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6122
        },
        {
          "rank": 2,
          "masteryId": 6131
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 4,
      "spell2Id": 32,
      "championId": 120,
      "profileIconId": 774,
      "summonerName": "Nuetzlich",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 43800105,
      "runes": [
        {
          "count": 6,
          "runeId": 5245
        },
        {
          "count": 2,
          "runeId": 5335
        }
      ],
      "masteries": [
        {
          "rank": 3,
          "masteryId": 6114
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6312
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6322
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6331
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6343
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6351
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6362
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "teamId": 100,
      "spell1Id": 13,
      "spell2Id": 7,
      "championId": 67,
      "profileIconId": 19,
      "summonerName": "Sonicmońgrel",
      "bot": false,
      "summonerId": 82267777,
      "runes": [
        {
          "count": 6,
          "runeId": 5245
        },
        {
          "count": 2,
          "runeId": 5335
        }
      ],
      "masteries": [
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6312
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6323
        },
        {
          "rank": 5,
          "masteryId": 6331
        },
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "masteryId": 6343
        },
        {
          "rank": 4,
          "masteryId": 6351
        }
      ]
    },
```

I'm struggling to get the "summonerNames" for each player and display them on the site :(

What jQuery do I need?

This is what gets the data:

```
function getCurrentGame(summonerID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/EUW1/" + summonerID + "?api_key=" + APIKEY,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        },
```

What do I need in here:

```
    success: function (resp) {


      }
```

To display the summoner names?

I have this in my HTML to simply build the list from the names:

```
Current Players (<span id="listPlayers"></span>)
<hr />
<span id="playerNames"></span>
```

Feel free to amend it in whatever way, I just really can't figure out how to list the player names :(

THANKS!!!

Comment: `resp.participants.summonerName` will do it

Comment: From that, you *should* be able to figure out how to access the rest

Comment: ignore the fact that your data was json. once you decode the json, it's a javascript object/array structure, and you access things in it like any other object/array.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole JSON object is the resp.

Let's say you want to access `"gameMode": "ARAM"`, it will be `resp.gameMode`.
Let's you want want to access `"summonerName": "MLG Elan"`, it will be `resp.participants.summonerName` ( because summonerName is inside an array called participants )

Comment: I keep getting Origin XXXXXXX is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( resp );
alert( obj.participants[0].summonerName);
```

Comment: Hey, wont that just display it in the console and not on the webpage? Thanks! :) Plus I keep getting Origin XXXXXXX is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: This looks unrelated. Are you making the request to another url? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error

Comment: Well I would presume the request is to an outside url as I'm using an API? I don't get why that is different though because the function uses data that is also generated from the same websites API. (E.g. Name to ID api request works but ID to current game API gives this error). Thankyou!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your json `data.participants` is an array, you can use `Array#map` to get all names:

```
var names = data.participants.map(function(item) {
     return item.summonerName;    
});
```

You don't need `jquery` for that

Answer (score 0):

**JSON**

```
var json = yourJSON;
```

**JavaScript**

```
var lenght = json.participants.length;
var summonerName = "";
for (i = 0; i < lenght ; i++){
  summonerName += json.participants[i].summonerName.toString() + ", ";
}
document.getElementById("playerNames").innerText = summonerName;
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="playerNames"></span>
```

Comment: I've tried this, console presents: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The data returned is from an API, I can confirm the API is working because it sends a request off to find the ID before using the ID in the above function. (If that makes sense).

Comment: PS - I've changed to jsonp in the "Get" area, now I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: I think you need to enable CORS in the configuration of the API. Look at this other problem. @apsillers explains how to get it working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: I still don't get why I'm able to access the data in function A, but can't access it in function B? Its the same web api, however function B uses the ID passed it from function A, would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The resp parameter is a JavaScript object created by the returned Json. summonerName is an attribute of each participant and participants is an array of objects. So you need to iterate through the participants array and get the name for each participant. Try something like this

```
  success: function (resp) {
    var participants = resp.participants,
        names = "",
        spanElement = document.getElementById("playerNames");

     participants.forEach(function(part){
       names = names + part.summonerName + " ";
     }

     spanElement.innerText = names ;
  }
```

Comment: I keep receiving; I keep getting Origin XXXXXXX is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin no matter what approach I try.

Comment: Looks like the api you try to use has not set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. Try using a proxy like this url:  "https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=https://euw.api.pvp.net/observer-mode/rest/consumer/getSpectatorGameInfo/EUW1/" + summonerID + "?api_key=" + APIKEY