# angularjs, ionic, and json decode using php

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic framework and AngularJS. I want to retrieve data from Mysql and decode to JSON using PHP so that I can use it in my Ionic App.

**Here is my PHP code**

```
<?php

/*

Here was my php codes to get all data from mysql and assign it to $episode array

*/

header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

echo json_encode($episode);


//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

When I run my App in the browser The console gave me this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://***Here Was My Url***/episodes.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**The code for controller**

```
$scope.posts = [];
var Url = "http://here was my url/episodes.php";

$http.get(Url)
.success(function(response){
  console.log("Reveived getPosts via HTTP: ", response, status);
  angular.forEach(response, function(child){
    $scope.posts.push(child);
  });
})
.error(function(response, status){
  console.log("Error while received response. " + status + response);
});
```

But when I run the App in a real device the array gave me this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b12vC.png

Hope you can help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your index.php file

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

Alternatively you could also add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Comment: Try this syntax(add headers), `$http({
      method: "Get",
      url: '...',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
   })
   .success(function(response){ //stuff
   });`

Comment: Still getting the same problem. I used WP-REST-API i from my wordpress site and it works but when using my own code NOT work. I tried also to generate json file and the problem still the same.

Comment: I had a similar problem but it was solved using the above code

Comment: I dont think so. Because the error you are getting indicates that you are making a cross origin request. Refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error]

Comment: I solved it by uploading my PHP script in another hosting :)