# Is there any way to avoid Cross-origin resource sharing check

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a home server in *domainX*, it returns HTML page containing
js part, which should GET data from *domainY*.
I can't control *domainY* return, which means that it it will not return any Allow-Origin headers etc.
I can't use JSON either because *domainY* does not support it.
postMessage may not work either, because I need to make search query
https://domainY/cars=blue&price_max=10000 etc.

I guess GET is the only way (XMLHttpRequest). I would like to avoid cors proxy because I try to keep server IO usage as low as possible.

Is there any tweak I could try without doing everything in the server side?

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error/9311585#9311585

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

The Same Origin Policy is designed to protect information that is private between the owner of the browser and the owner of *domainY*.

You can't get the browser to fetch arbitrary data (with the benefit of the browser's cookies and the browser's IP address) and then make it available to your JavaScript.

*domainY* might me my webmail, e-banking, or secure corporate Intranet. You aren't allowed to touch it using my browser.