# how to play the youtube video in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

```js
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('video', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player.playVideo();
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TTQK9aWZVds?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

The above code is to run the video on mobile browser, but it is not playing!

it's working in web browser

Comment: You are aware that browser vendors limit the ability to auto-play videos on mobile to a very specific set of circumstances, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error).

"Javascript is limited by the 'same origin policy' for security reasons so that a malicious script cannot contact a remote server and send sensitive data."

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('video', {
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
      });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      player.playVideo();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TTQK9aWZVds?enablejsapi=1" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I updated my answer again with a link to another stack overflow topic, were the answer explains this scenario very good.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately video autoplay (as well as JS triggered playing) is forbidden on mobile devices. Video should be started by user action only. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Examples